# Button not showing console log function

Tags: javascript, html, css

This may be a simple question, but i am a "starter" in javascript, and i managed to do a simple form just the way i wanted it to be, (on the look side of things), i was trying to do a alert box, but in the middle of testing i saw that when trying to do a console log, it wasn't showing up in the console the message, if anyone know what is the problem, i would appreciate :)

Here are the codes: (in order, javascript, css, html)

```js
const cadForm = document.getElementById('Formulario');

function alert(){
    Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: 'Ops..',
        text: 'Pelo visto a placa do veiculo não está cadastrada.',
        footer: '<a href="">Gostaria de cadastrar?</a>'
      })
}

if (cadForm){
    cadForm.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
    
        console.log("Success");
    })
}
```

```css
/* ===== Google Font Import - Poppins ===== */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg,#ef1570 ,#fea858);
}
.container{
    position: relative;
    max-width: 900px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 0 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.container header{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #333;
}
.container header::before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -2px;
    height: 3px;
    width: 27px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #4070f4;
}
.container form{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 16px;
    min-height: 490px;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container form .form{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.container form .form.second{
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translateX(100%);
}
form.secActive .form.second{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    transform: translateX(0);
}
form.secActive .form.first{
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.container form .title{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 6px 0;
    color: #333;
}
.container form .fields{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
form .fields .input-field{
    display: flex;
    width: calc(100% / 3 - 15px);
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 4px 0;
}
.input-field label{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #2e2e2e;
}
.input-field input, select{
    outline: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 0 15px;
    height: 42px;
    margin: 8px 0;
}
.input-field input :focus,
.input-field select:focus{
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
}
.input-field select,
.input-field input[type="date"]{
    color: #707070;
}
.input-field input[type="date"]:valid{
    color: #333;
}
.container form button, .backBtn{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 45px;
    max-width: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 25px 0;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg,#ef1570 ,#fea858);
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.container form .btnText{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
form button:hover{
    background: linear-gradient(90deg,#d2759c ,#efc399);
}
form button i,
form .backBtn i{
    margin: 0 6px;
}
form .backBtn i{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
form .buttons{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
form .buttons button , .backBtn{
    margin-right: 14px;
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
    .container form{
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .container form::-webkit-scrollbar{
       display: none;
    }
    form .fields .input-field{
        width: calc(100% / 2 - 15px);
    }
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
    form .fields .input-field{
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.swal2-footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #4070f4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FretNet - Cadastro</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./bxs-truck.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
    
    <!----======== CSS ======== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/register.css">
     
    <!----===== Iconscout CSS ===== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">

    <!--<title>Responsive Regisration Form </title>--> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>Faça seu Cadastro</header>

        <form action="#">
            <div class="form first" id="Formulario">
                <div class="details personal">
                    <span class="title">Insira seus dados</span>

                    <div class="fields">
                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label>Nome Completo</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Insira seu nome" >
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label>Data de nascimento</label>
                            <input type="date" placeholder="Insira sua data de nascimento" >
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Insira seu email" >
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label>Numero de telefone</label>
                            <input type="number" placeholder="Digite seu telefone" >
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label>Gênero</label>
                            <select >
                                <option disabled selected>Selecione seu Gênero</option>
                                <option>Masculino</option>
                                <option>Feminino</option>
                                <option>Outros</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label>Ocupação</label>
                            <select >
                                <option disabled selected>Você é um autonomo?</option>
                                <option>Sim</option>
                                <option>Não</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="details ID">
                    <span class="title">Dados Judiciais</span>

                    <div class="fields">
                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label>Cpf</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Insira seu Cpf" >
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label>RG</label>
                            <input type="number" placeholder="Digite seu RG" >
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label>N° de Registro da CNH</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Insira no numero da Cnh" >
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label>Placa do Veículo</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Caso seja autonomo" >
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label>Data de Emissão</label>
                            <input type="date" placeholder="Insira a data de emissão" >
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label>Data de validade</label>
                            <input type="date" placeholder="Insira a Data de validade" >
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <button class="nextBtn" id="cadastro" type="submit" value="Cadastro">
                        <span class="btnText">Submit</span>
                        <i class="uil uil-navigator"></i>
                    </button>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="assets/js/sweetalert2.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/sweetalert.js"></script>

    <!--<script src="script.js"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your id was on a div, not on a form

You also have to `preventDefault()` if you want to see the console.log, otherwise the site will reload

```js
const cadForm = document.getElementById('Formulario');

function alert(){
    Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: 'Ops..',
        text: 'Pelo visto a placa do veiculo não está cadastrada.',
        footer: '<a href="">Gostaria de cadastrar?</a>'
      })
}

if (cadForm){
    cadForm.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log("Success");
    })
}
```

```css
/* ===== Google Font Import - Poppins ===== */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg,#ef1570 ,#fea858);
}
.container{
    position: relative;
    max-width: 900px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 0 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.container header{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #333;
}
.container header::before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -2px;
    height: 3px;
    width: 27px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #4070f4;
}
.container form{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 16px;
    min-height: 490px;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container form .form{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.container form .form.second{
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translateX(100%);
}
form.secActive .form.second{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    transform: translateX(0);
}
form.secActive .form.first{
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.container form .title{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 6px 0;
    color: #333;
}
.container form .fields{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
form .fields .input-field{
    display: flex;
    width: calc(100% / 3 - 15px);
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 4px 0;
}
.input-field label{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #2e2e2e;
}
.input-field input, select{
    outline: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 0 15px;
    height: 42px;
    margin: 8px 0;
}
.input-field input :focus,
.input-field select:focus{
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
}
.input-field select,
.input-field input[type="date"]{
    color: #707070;
}
.input-field input[type="date"]:valid{
    color: #333;
}
.container form button, .backBtn{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 45px;
    max-width: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 25px 0;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg,#ef1570 ,#fea858);
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.container form .btnText{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
form button:hover{
    background: linear-gradient(90deg,#d2759c ,#efc399);
}
form button i,
form .backBtn i{
    margin: 0 6px;
}
form .backBtn i{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
form .buttons{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
form .buttons button , .backBtn{
    margin-right: 14px;
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
    .container form{
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .container form::-webkit-scrollbar{
       display: none;
    }
    form .fields .input-field{
        width: calc(100% / 2 - 15px);
    }
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
    form .fields .input-field{
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.swal2-footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #4070f4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FretNet - Cadastro</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./bxs-truck.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
    
    <!----======== CSS ======== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/register.css">
     
    <!----===== Iconscout CSS ===== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">

    <!--<title>Responsive Regisration Form </title>--> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>Faça seu Cadastro</header>

        <form action="#"  id="Formulario">
            <div class="form first">
                <div class="details personal">
                    <span class="title">Insira seus dados</span>

                    <div class="fields">
                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label>Nome Completo</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Insira seu nome" >
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label>Data de nascimento</label>
                            <input type="date" placeholder="Insira sua data de nascimento" >
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Insira seu email" >
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label>Numero de telefone</label>
                            <input type="number" placeholder="Digite seu telefone" >
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label>Gênero</label>
                            <select >
                                <option disabled selected>Selecione seu Gênero</option>
                                <option>Masculino</option>
                                <option>Feminino</option>
                                <option>Outros</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label>Ocupação</label>
                            <select >
                                <option disabled selected>Você é um autonomo?</option>
                                <option>Sim</option>
                                <option>Não</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="details ID">
                    <span class="title">Dados Judiciais</span>

                    <div class="fields">
                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label>Cpf</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Insira seu Cpf" >
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label>RG</label>
                            <input type="number" placeholder="Digite seu RG" >
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label>N° de Registro da CNH</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Insira no numero da Cnh" >
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label>Placa do Veículo</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Caso seja autonomo" >
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label>Data de Emissão</label>
                            <input type="date" placeholder="Insira a data de emissão" >
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label>Data de validade</label>
                            <input type="date" placeholder="Insira a Data de validade" >
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <button class="nextBtn" id="cadastro" type="submit" value="Cadastro">
                        <span class="btnText">Submit</span>
                        <i class="uil uil-navigator"></i>
                    </button>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="assets/js/sweetalert2.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/sweetalert.js"></script>

    <!--<script src="script.js"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```